# TypeError: (intermediate value).addField(...).setTitle(...).addFields(...).setColor(...).setThumbnail(...).addFooter is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
    case 'botinfo':
    const botinfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addField("**Bot Name:**", bot.user.username)
    .setTitle("**Bot Information**")
    .addFields(
        { name: '**Version⚙️ :**', value: bot.user.version },
        { name: '**Created by:**', value: ''},
        { name: '**Created at:**', value: bot.user.createdAt},
        { name: '**help:**', value: 'for more information about help with bot check text channel bothelp'},
)
    .setColor(0xF8F8F8)
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addFooter("For More Embed Commands Type !embeds")
    message.channel.send(botinfo);
    break;
```

Comment: please elaborate on the problem.

Comment: what do you mean? @Hadi Pawar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by `addFooter()` which is not a method, you need to use [`setFooter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setFooter)